# How to return an array with the step of the sum of the previous value?

Tags: javascript

How to return an array with the step of the sum of the previous value?

I have an input number that is 1000
I want to get [1000, 2000, 3000 ... 10000]

I'm trying to:

```
  const range = (i: number, o: number) => {
    const arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(
      (accumulator: any, currentValue: any, index: any, array: any) => {
        console.log((array[index] = accumulator + currentValue));
        return 1;
      },
      10000
    );
  };

  range(1000, 10000);
```

Comment: step sum in what sense, can you give complete example?

Comment: are you looking for multiple of a number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.from` and provide the first argument as an object with `length` property that is equal to the step, and second argument as mapping function that simply multiply the index and step:

```js
const range = (start,end) => 
    Array.from( {length: end/start} ,(_,i) => (i+1) * start )
      
console.log(range(1000,10000))
```

Comment: Fancy but can you explain for what the underscore "_" stand, please?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function range(start, end) {
    var arr = []; // Start with an empty array

    /* Start a counter at the start value, and increment it
     * by the start value while it is less than or equal to
     * the end value. Push this value into arr each time
     */
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += start) {
        arr.push(i);
    }

    return arr; // Return the array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple loop and check if `number * index <= max` while adding values to new array:

```js
  const range = (number, max) => {
    let index = 1;
    let newArray = [];

    do {
      newArray.push(number * index);
      index++;
    } while (number * index <= max);
    
    return newArray;
  };

  console.log(range(1000, 10000));

  console.log(range(10000, 10000));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const range = (start, end) => {
  let acc = [];
  for (let i = start; i <= end; i = i + start) {
    acc = [...acc, i];
  }
  return acc;
}
```

If not, please elaborate your example to clearly state the intent of `...step of the sum of the previous value`.